# INNER JOIN two columns to one

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's what my 2 tables look like

Table A

```
userID | adminID
```

Table B

```
IDs | fName
```

In Table A, both the `userID` and `adminID` are found in table B. I'm trying to return the full name for each.

This is the SQL I am currently using

```
SELECT fName
FROM tableB
INNER JOIN tableA ON tableA.userID = tableB.IDs.
```

This is where I'm stuck. This only returns 1 column. I would like it to return each `fName` in their own column.

Comment: "both the userID and adminID are found in table B." - that smells like it's modelled incorrectly.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, if this is more of an employee and their admin point-of-contact and you want it on each row, such that different employees could have different admin contacts..

```
select
      a.UserID,
      u.fname UserFirstName,
      au.fname AdminFirstName
   from
      tableA a
         join tableB u
            on a.userID = u.IDs
         join tableB au
            on a.adminID = au.IDs
```

Now, if the admin ID is not always available, just change the second join to a LEFT JOIN.  Notice different alias references of the same table to get context of each first name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `UNION`?

```
SELECT fName FROM tableB INNER JOIN tableA ON tableA.userID=tableB.IDs
UNION
SELECT fName FROM tableB INNER JOIN tableA ON tableA.adminID=tableB.IDs
```

Comment: Thank you but i used the first guys answer